# xamarin forms clear picker selection

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin along with c# and xaml so this has been quite a learning experience. I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple task (clear a picker selection), but it has proven to become quite a challenge.

Desired functionality: a page with a picker selection, make a selection, save the selection to a variable, move to a different page and then clear the selection made so when going back to the first page there is not a selection made.

I've tried using picker.Items.Clear() and setting the SelectedIndex  = -1 but I have consistently gotten the OutOfRangeException.  I tried this post but couldn't get any options working:  [How to clear picker if It is selected in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676143/how-to-clear-picker-if-it-is-selected-in-xamarin-forms)

I don't want to set the picker to the first option, I want it to be empty so the picker title is displayed which is how it works when it first runs but when I make a selection and move to the next page, when I go back, my initial selection is still made.

Hopefully that all makes sense what I'm trying to achieve.  Below is my basic code, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Select an option:" 
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
        />

        <Picker x:Name="OptionSelect"
            Title="Click to Select"
            SelectedIndexChanged="OptionSelect_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
        />      
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 1");
        OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 2");
        OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 3");
    }

    public void OptionSelect_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var option = OptionSelect.Items[OptionSelect.SelectedIndex];

        //OptionSelect.Items.Clear();
        //OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 1");
        //OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 2");
        //OptionSelect.Items.Add("Option 3");

        //OptionSelect.SelectedIndex = -1;

        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> clear picker selection?

Set the `SelectedItem` property on the `Picker` instance to `null`.

So using your code example and preventing the re-firing of the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event when assigning it `null`:

```
public void OptionSelect_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var option = OptionSelect.SelectedItem;
    // Prevent setting the SelectedItem from refiring event
    OptionSelect.SelectedIndexChanged -= OptionSelect_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    OptionSelect.SelectedItem = null;
    OptionSelect.SelectedIndexChanged += OptionSelect_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    // Do something with option object
}
```

Comment: wonderful, that worked.  I don't understand yet how -= and += works but I think a small issue is caused from using this:  After making an option selection and getting moved to Page 1, I have to click the navigation page back button twice before it goes back to the starting page.  Any thoughts why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.T `how -= and += works` When you set the `.SelectedItem` to a new value, its index changed event gets fired, so by removing the handler, you avoid it being called a 2nd time when you set it to null. Not sure about the page issue, are you calling `.PushAsync(new Page1());` just once?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You were in the right direction with the page issue, I was calling `.PushAsync(new Page1());` just once but it appears when I set it back to null the change event got triggered again which called the push again.  I added a check for null to determine when to move to Page1 and that seemed to take care of it.